# Fetching data from local .json file in react.js returns multiple errors

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a json file named autofill.json and it's created to autofill a search bar when pressed on.

the autofill.json is a test file that's why it looks like this.

```
        [
  {
    "a": {
      "apple": {
        "name": "apple",
        "href": "https://www.apple.com/"
      },
      "armadillo": {
        "name": "armadillo",
        "href": "https://www.armadillo.com/"
      }
    },
    "b": {
      "box": {
        "name": "apple",
        "href": "https://www.berserk.com/"
      },
      "berserk": {
        "name": "berserk",
        "href": "https://www.berserk.com/"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

---

The .json file is then fetched in the file named FetchAndParseResults.js

```
    import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

const FetchAndParseResults = (url) => {
  return fetch(url).then(response => {
    const parsedJson = response.json()
    return parsedJson
  })
}

export default FetchAndParseResults
```

---

The data that gets fetched is used in searchcontainer.js where everything gets placed in, the search etc.

```
    import React from 'react'
import Searchbar from './index.js'
import FetchAndParseResults from './FetchAndParseResults.js'

class SearchContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
      results: []
    }

    performSearch = event => {
      return FetchAndParseResults('static/autofill.json').then(data => {
        this.setState({ results: data })
      })
    }

    render () {
      console.log('performSearch event', this.performSearch)
      console.log('data inside performSearch', this.state.results)
      return (
        <Searchbar
          performSearch={this.performSearch}
          results={this.state.results}
        />
      )
    }
    }

export default SearchContainer
```

---

Then to map through the data that is in autofill.json there is a file named autofill.js

```
    import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Styles from './searchbar.scss'

const AutoFill = (props) => {
  console.log('proppppppsss', props)
  const results = props.results || []

  return (
    <ul className={Styles.searchUl}>
      {results.map(({ name, href }) => (
        <li className={Styles.searchLi} key={href}>
          <a className={Styles.searchA} href={href} target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer' key={href}>
            {name}
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

AutoFill.propTypes = {
  results: PropTypes.array
}

export default AutoFill
```

---

the Searchbar component in (index.js) that is being used in searchcontainer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Styles from './searchbar.scss'
import Icon from '../../components/icon/icon'
import Search from '../../components/form-input/search'
import AutoFill from './autofill'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class Searchbar extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      className: Styles.input,
      icon: Styles.icon__wrapper,
      value: []
    }
    this.input = React.createRef()
  }

  openInput = () => {
    this.setState({
      className: Styles.input__active,
      icon: Styles.iconWidth
    }, () => {
      this.input.focus()
    })
    this.props.onOpen && this.props.onOpen()
  }

  closeInput = () => {
    this.setState({
      className: Styles.input,
      icon: Styles.icon__wrapper
    })
    this.props.onClose && this.props.onClose()
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    let value = event.target.value
    this.setState({ value })
    this.props.performSearch(value)
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
  }

  render () {
    console.log('results', this.props.results)
    console.log('state.value', this.state.value)
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className={Styles.search}>
          <div className={this.state.icon}>
            <Icon className={Styles.icon__wrapper} iconName='faSearch' onClick={this.openInput} />
          </div>
          <Search autoComplete='off' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} id='search' tabIndex='0' myref={input => { this.input = input }} className={this.state.className} onBlur={this.closeInput} placeholder='Search' />
        </form>
        <div>
          <AutoFill results={this.props.results} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Search.propTypes = {
  performSearch: PropTypes.func,
  results: PropTypes.array
}
```

---

When i try to refer to a what is in the json file from the search i receive the error,

> GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

And

> about:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON
>   at position 0

The second error is fixed by doing

```
const parsedJson = response.text(
```

instead of

```
const parsedJson = response.json()
```

to get more information where/what the error takes place. But by doing this i receive the error,

> searchcontainer.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

---

I've tried to run it from npm build instead of running it in a dev environment which didn't fix it.

I read that a mock url should work but then again i want to acces it from a file and not from a url?

Any help would be highly appreciated and looked into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been solved, The main issue was with defining const names such as `const results = []` which should've been `const results = props.results || []`.

The code has been updated incase you have problems aswell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in the fetch call. If you look at the error message `GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)`
You can see that it is trying to append an object to the URL `localhost:3000/`.

You are getting the `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` error because the response of your fetch request is probably a 404 page. The < is most likely the first char of `<html>`

Comment: Yes that's what i was thinking but i'm refering to a file so why does it append to a url?
<br>
For reason i changed response.json() to response.text() to look further into the error what it exactly means than it says that results in searchcontainer.js is not a function.

Comment: Do you have more calls to fetch? The one in your file fetchresults.js makes a call to `static/mockData/autofill.json`, but the error in your question looks different

Comment: Oh, i tried to refer it to a url but then i had issues with creating a mock url in react ill edit that right now it should be, 'autofill.json'

Answer (score 0):

To access the JSON object in your React files, you can simply do an importation like so;

```
import * as autofillData from 'autofill.json';
```

It will be returned as a JSON object.

I believe you are using the `isomorphic-fetch` package wrongly, if you look at their source code, https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/blob/master/fetch-npm-node.js#L5 , they are accepting a URL to make a call to the API URL which will return a promise or a JSON object depending on the implementation of the API that you are calling.

If you were to dive deeper into the open-source code here (https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/blob/master/fetch-npm-node.js#L8) , you will notice that `isomorphic-fetch` package is using another package `node-fetch` to do their fetch call, which accepts the API URL and the method request options to call the API with. (As stated here; https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/master/src/index.js#L34)

To continue with your test, perhaps this might be the solution you'd prefer?

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import * as autofillData from 'autofill.json'; //test data

const FetchResults = event => {
  return fetch('/https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'') //mockURL, to be replaced with real API
    .then(response => {
      // const parsedJson = response.json(); // TODO: un-comment this line when the real API url is usable
      const parsedJson = autofillData; // TODO: remove this line when mocking is done and the real API URL is ready
      return parsedJson;
    })
}

export default FetchResults;
```

To have a mock URL placeholder, I would suggest https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ to prevent your fetch result to return an unexpected error during test mocking.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I've tried your method with the jsonplaceholder api not much is happening since my first fetch should also work, i assume this because i get the same error. The error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
    at searchcontainer.js:12

Comment: Because there is no `response` field in `data`. In your search container component, `data` would be your autofill JSON value and since there is no field called `response` there, it would return that error.

Comment: Isn't this: this.setState({ results: data.response.results }) the field where the data should be returned to?

Comment: Check what is in your `data`

Comment: When i consolelog the data i receive,
https://gyazo.com/f680e9ace3d2d92e6d2ce1e796c65cda
It doesn't know that data.response.results is json data? Since it is returning an event.

Comment: I need to know what are you logging exactly and where at. From this result, it looks like you're logging `performSearch` instead.

Comment: Yeah i had console logged the performSearch instead of the data itself i noticed this a couple days ago. When i console log the data i get this:
https://gyazo.com/83b42456bf347f1efe65588b7d36e083
Which is good because the fetch is actually working.but the only problem now is to show it as an autofill when pressed on the search :) which i couldn't get to work aswell. Sorry for the wrong console.log

Comment: Check the props that you are passing into your AutoFill component. I believe the problem lies in your fetching of these props in your component; this line. `const results = props.a || []`

Comment: I had changed that line else i wouldn't get any data i have updated the codes in my post.
Instead of ``const results = props.a || []`` i have done ``const results = []`` So it can return an object.

Comment: I honestly think you have no idea what you are doing. `const results = []` is setting your `results` variable to an empty array. And then you `map` the empty `results` variable array. It doesn't make sense at all. I'm trying to help you here, but I need you to think thoroughly on what you want to do and what you are doing exactly to achieve that.

Comment: I saw that today to since i was following a tutorial to achieve this, I have changed ``const results = []`` to ``const results = props.results || []`` so it actually has data.
Sorry for the inconveniece i'm just trying to learn. i'll now update the codes to what i have done so it's clear for you to :)

Comment: Great for taking the initiative to learn but please try to understand the whole data flow and the code in the tutorials, instead of just following tutorials, all the best in your learning journey!